# How to tersely insert a default-constructed object into a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

All the overloads of `std::vector::insert()` require a value argument, which is the item to be inserted. However, my item type is complicated and I would rather have an empty-constructed item inserted. That is, I'm looking for a way to do the following without the type name duplication.

```
std::vector<Long_and_complicated_type_name> v;
...
v.insert(iter, Long_and_complicated_type_name());
```

The same issue exists for `push_back` though I'm primarily interested in `insert`.

Comment: What is an "empty item"?

Comment: An object that results from an empty constructor invocation. Is there a proper name?

Comment: A "default-initialized object", or perhaps a "default-constructed object" if it is of class type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::vector` methods `emplace` and `emplace_back` can serve that purpose.

```
template< class... Args > 
iterator emplace( const_iterator pos, Args&&... args );
```

The forwarded `args` can be absent, allowing

```
std::vector<Long_and_complicated_type_name> v;
...
v.emplace(iter);
```

and even

```
v.emplace_back();
```

Answer (score 6):

another way:

```
#include <vector>

struct supercalafragalisticexpialadocious {};

int main()
{
  std::vector<supercalafragalisticexpialadocious> v;

  v.push_back({});
}
```